# Is there a reliable alternative for .on('change')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a car builder with multiple steps and I have managed to make it validate, unlock the next step, load the content of the next step with AJAX and change to it when clicking a label with a radio button in it by using `.on('change', 'input')` and triggering a *click* on the Next button inside the current step.

The problem is that Safari on iOS is less consistent than Android browsers when it comes to the *change* event and doesn't fire it when a label is touched (input is checked), therefore making it impossible to go to the next step. It works fine on Android browsers.

I have seen somewhere that the *blur* event might be more reliable but it doesn't work very well for my application as I then need to trigger it as soon as an input is focused like so:

```
$steps.on('blur', 'input', function () {
    // ...
})
.on('focus', 'input', function(){
    let $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.blur();
    }, 1)
});
```

It's not clean at all and doesn't seem to fire on inputs inside a slick carousel. It also fires when clicking on an input that's already selected, triggering an unnecessary AJAX call for the next step and overwriting all selected inputs in the next steps.

Is there any alternative event (Js or jQuery) to *change* or *blur* that works reliably in Safari as well as every other browsers (including IE11, sadly)?

Comment: What do you mean by "Safari doesn't trigger change when label is touched"? Change event is like blur, but only when the value changed. Which label do you mean? You need to select something else a field for change to take effect.

Comment: As already stated, it isn't clear what you mean, but it sounds like you are misunderstanding what can trigger a `change` event.  [From the docs](https://api.jquery.com/change/): *The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.  For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.*

Comment: I didn't know about that last part because I've never had a radio or checkbox input not trigger change when checking it, on phone or on desktop.